# Automatic insertion of a style tag in browser html

Tags: html, css

I have code with proper working style sheet linked and working in IE, eclipse browser, but running the local host in chrome web browser shows me a empty style tag inserted in the header and I am sure there is no JS or J Query is not used yet.

[image: Empty style tag]

The head section from my code

[image: My code from the editor]

Can some one help me out why this is happening?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please show your `<head>` section HTML from your file?

Comment: This empty style tag shouldn't have any effect on your site. What does your source look like?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal please see the head section from my editor now..

Comment: @Dave bcz of the empty tag of style sheet the other styles are not being loaded, or either being over loaded causing a portion of  the page being display : none

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed in chrome?

Comment: What kind of plug-ins or extensions do you have installed (or even used to have) installed chrome? Possible solutions: try disabling or uninstalling all chrome extensions. Or, if that doesn't work, nuke chrome and re-install.

Comment: I think thats the issue with my "adblocker plugin"  !! thanks for the awesome help.

Comment: Don't give partial information. Best you can share in jsfiddle like something your html file with lesser content and css files to work on that.

Comment: Any particular reason there's a `</link>` end tag in the code?

Comment: I'm asking because the new `<style>` element just happens to have taken the place of said end tag.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal keep ur comment as the answer so that I can make your comment as the correct answer :)

Comment: Done @srikanth, please check!